Modding Minecraft Forge 1.20.4: How to change edit-screens for build-in signs and hanging-signs?
I created a mod, where i recreated model, text-layout and other stuff for the build-in signs in an older version of minecraft forge, where it worked properly.
Now i´m updating it, but i found a problem:
When i open the sign edit screen, i want to instantly replace it with my own.
But the class has now 3 constructor arguments.
The first one is the SignTileEntity, and i tried to get it through the ObfuscationReflectionHelper, but none of the names of the matching fild in the class AbstractSignEditScreen can be found during a testrun
How can i get the used SignBlockEntity to pass it into the constructor of my edited screen?
